# NPE in WebService vert.x when returning OperationResponse()

Tags: java, vert.x

I have taken the [web-api-service-example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/web-api-service-example) and is trying to adapt it to a Mongo based backend. The code looks almost identical except I have added (duplicate/rename) the Transaction.class to a User.class as well as the Service implementation and web handler.

I am trying to get the user json from the URL /users/username. Mongo correctly retrieves it.

My question is this: I have two pieces of code, one working (returning the user json) and one not working throwing a NPE.

Not working code (it compiles and I cannot understand why is not working):

```
@Override
  public void getUser(
    String username,
    OperationRequest context, Handler<AsyncResult<OperationResponse>> resultHandler) {
      resultHandler.handle(
        persistence.getUser(username)
          .compose(user -> {
            if (user.isPresent()) {
              System.err.println("D: " + user.get());
              return Future.succeededFuture(OperationResponse.completedWithJson(user.get()));
            } else  {
              return Future.succeededFuture(new OperationResponse().setStatusCode(404).setStatusMessage("Not Found"));
            }
          })
      );
  }
```

It thows the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Failed to handleMessage. address: __vertx.reply.1
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.vertx.ext.web.api.OperationResponseConverter.fromJson(OperationResponseConverter.java:15)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.api.OperationResponse.<init>(OperationResponse.java:30)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.api.contract.impl.RouteToEBServiceHandler.lambda$handle$1(RouteToEBServiceHandler.java:35)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$convertHandler$2(EventBusImpl.java:342)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:278)
...
...
D: {"_id":"5fbebeb97d3c4c0e48f9c7e0","email":"some@user.dk","firstName":"firstname","id":0,"lastName":"lastname","password":"password","phone":"+4512345678","username":"username"}
```

The NPE is thrown first, then the `System.err.println("D: " + user.get());` gets executed and prints the user. The browser then waits forever for a reply.

When this piece of code working fine:

```
  @Override
  public void getUser(
    String username,
    OperationRequest context, Handler<AsyncResult<OperationResponse>> resultHandler) {
      persistence.getUser(username).compose(user -> {
        if (user.isPresent()) {
          resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(OperationResponse.completedWithJson(user.get())));
          return Future.succeededFuture();
        } else  {
          resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new OperationResponse().setStatusCode(404).setStatusMessage("Not Found")));
          return Future.failedFuture("Error");
        }
      });
  }
```

One would presume that returing the Future.succeededFuture() to the resultHandler.handle() would be the correct way to do it? But it throws the NPE!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this getUser() persistance method:

```
  @Override
  public Future<JsonObject> getUser(String username) {
    Promise<JsonObject> promise = Promise.promise();
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, mongoconfig);
    JsonObject query = new JsonObject().put("username", username);
    mongoClient.findOne(collectionName, query, null, promise::handle);
    return promise.future();
  }
```

and this service handler:

```
  @Override
  public void getUser(
    String username,
    OperationRequest context, Handler<AsyncResult<OperationResponse>> resultHandler) {
      persistence.getUser(username)
        .onSuccess(jsonObject -> {
          resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(OperationResponse.completedWithJson(jsonObject)));
        });
  }
```

Great code comes with great responsability... One has to love Futures (once understood) :)

Comment: Your service handler code in this answer is not semantically equivalent to the one in the question (you don't propagate the failures back). That's what you were looking for?